# What is the opposite of 'curse of knowledge' or reverse of Zen 'Shoshin'?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to see if there is a term for someone that assumes because they have some level of expertise in a given field, they refused to listen to others (who do not have similar pedigrees) who have input on the assumption their lack of experience makes the input irrelevant.

Is see there is a term 'curse of knowledge' where one assumes others have the 'same' knowledge (which would be one form of opposite of this) and another Zen term 'Shoshin' that means open minded and willing to accept input from any/many/all sources.

But I'm referring to someone who has been biased by their own field and the perceived image of their own expertise in that field and thus will not listen to anyone 'outside' their expertise regardless of the quality or nature of the input.

In a manner of speaking, it would also be antithetical to Dunn & Kruger effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be related: [Which is the scientific name of stubbornness?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5878/7001) and [Is there a name for a scientist's resistance to disconfirmation of his or her theories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8053/7001).

Comment: I was wondering this myself. It’s like Mansplaining, but for people who do it to the general public or their friends. They assume the things they are saying is new to the other person,
and unnecessarily explain it like they’re teaching a lecture. I’ve been trying to find the term for this as well.

Comment: mansplaining is an invented concept. Pretense created by the pretentious so they have something else to complain about.